# Calc of Probabilities with a adjacency matrix

Tags: c++, math

This is a programming contest problem. It's input can be found [here](https://www.ime.usp.br/~cef/VIImaratona/prova/insesols/drunk.in) and the output [here](https://www.ime.usp.br/~cef/VIImaratona/prova/insesols/drunk.sol).

A drunk man wants to leave the bar and back to his home. But he can't remember where his home is located. So, He will knock on every dor of the city and wait for someone of his family to receive him (Always someone will be waiting to receive him).

Given a adjacency matrix **A**. Where each value **(i,j)** represents the probability of the drunk man leave the i'th place and get to j'th place. What is the probability that the drunk man don't find his home with at most **m** steps ?

Until now i don't even make sense of what problem is this. Searching the web and books i've found that to calculate the probability of leave the node **i** a get to node **j** in exactly **m** steps is given by the position **(i,j)** on the **m'th** power of the **A** matrix (A^m). And that the probability of the drunk man don't get to his home can be calculated directly or by calculating 1 - the probability of the drunk man reach his house (P(A) = 1 - P(not A)).

> The first line of the input consist of a line with four integers **n** (0 <= n <= 100),**t** (0 < t <= 100),**k** (0 < k <= n), **m** (0 < m <= 100), that represent respectively the number of houses, the bar position, the house of the drunk man and the amount of tries. After this line, n lines with n integers is given describing the matrix of probabilities. 0 mark the end of input.

The output is given in two lines for each test case and must be of the form:

> Instancia **d**:
>   **v**
>   where d represents the number of the instance (starting at 1) and v is the probability rounded to 6 decimal places. There is a blank line between each test case.

Example of input:

> 2 1 2 1
>   0.5 0.5
>   0.5 0.5
>   3 1 2 2
>   0.25 0.25 0.5
>   0.25 0.5 0.25
>   0.5 0.25 0.25
>   0

Example of output:

> Instancia 1
>   0.500000
>
> Instancia 2
>   0.562500

Any help with an algorithm , book , website or hint is appreciated;

With the information that i have to solve this problem until now i only can make this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Matrix {
    double v[100][100];
    int row, col; // row x col

    Matrix(int n, int m) {
        memset(v, 0, sizeof(v));
        col = n;
        row = m;
    }

    Matrix operator*(const Matrix& x) const {
        Matrix ret(row, x.col);
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < col; k++) {
                if (v[i][k])
                    for(int j = 0; j < x.col; j++)
                        ret.v[i][j] += v[i][k] * x.v[k][j];
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
};


int main(){
    int n,t,k,m;
    int inst = 0;
    while(scanf("%d %d %d %d",&n,&t,&k,&m) == 4){
        Matrix mat(n,n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                scanf("%lf",&mat.v[i][j]);

        //identity matrix
        Matrix aux(n,n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            aux.v[i][i] = 1;


        //take the power of the matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
            aux = aux*mat;

            /* PRINT MATRIX
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                    printf("%lf ",aux.v[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
             */

        }
        printf("Instancia %d\n%.6lf\n\n",++inst,aux.v[t-1][k-1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The rollback was made to validate the answer again =) As recommendation of stack overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said stgatilov, you forget that he won't leave home once he get there.

But no need for dynamic programming. Just change the probability matrix a little: if his home is at place `i`, then change **the probability from `i` to `i`** to `1`, and for any `j` not equal to `i`, change **the probability from `i` to `j`** to `0`.

Then it should work fine.

Note: there is a further possible optimization. Instead of multiplying your matrix `m` times, you can use [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: I've implemented it =P with the hints you gave me. Accepted.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you have forgotten that the man can get home in **less** than *m* steps. Now you are counting probability that he won't be at home after **exactly** *m* steps, given that he does not stop for any reason.

I think you'd better implement some dynamic programming. For instance *R[i, p]* = probability that the man does not get home in *i* steps, and after *i*-step step he would be at place *p*. Recalculating is somewhat similar to matrix multiplication, the answer is got by summing appropriate entries of the table *R*.

Comment: Thanks for the hint =)